# how to maintain parent path of symlinked folder

Tags: linux, macos

As we all know how to creat a symlink

```
ln -s /home/foo/test /home/bar/test2
```

link the folder `/home/foo/test` to the `/home/bar/test2` symbol link

but when I enter `/home/bar/test2`, and execute `ls ../`

it will output the content of `/home/foo`, not `/home/bar`

My OS is Mac OSX 10.8.5

Comment: You have taken a shortcut and want to come back taking same shortcut ?????

Comment: have you tried ls -P ../